# Apache2 server down Private key not found

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server

```
 AH02579: Init: Private key not found
```

I have

1. ubuntu
2. root
3. www-data

   users

   my root and ubuntu can access the key file

   `nano /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.x.com/fullchain.pem`

And when i do

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

my website gave 521 and acpache logs show

```
AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?) private key$
AH00016: Configuration Failed
[Mon May 25 17:19:12.374354 2020] [ssl:error] [pid 4962:tid 140701433358208] AH02579: Init: Private key not found
```

I have done

```
sudo chmod 700 /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.x.com/
sudo chmod 400 /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.x.com/fullchain.pem
```

But still apache can not find key

---

### Update

Hey i think this is something that can help answering 
I do have 2 pem files 

And when i go to previous private key and do

```
ubuntu@ip-172:/etc/letsencrypt/live/app.x.com$ openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -noout -check
RSA key ok
```

and if i use this then server is running fine 
But when i add my other subdomain and created certificate for it then

```
ubuntu@ip-172:/etc/letsencrypt/live/server.x.com$ openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -noout -check
Error opening Private Key privkey.pem
140659156387480:error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:bss_file.c:398:fopen('privkey.pem','r')
140659156387480:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
unable to load Private Key
```

And when i load this in .conf file then apache2 give error

---

```
   ubuntu@ip-172:/etc/letsencrypt/live/server.x.com$ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

After running this command

```
  Generating a 4096 bit RSA private key
    ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................++
    ..........++
    unable to write 'random state'
    writing new private key to 'key.pem'
    Enter PEM pass phrase:
    Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
    -----
    You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
    into your certificate request.
    What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
    There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
    For some fields there will be a default value,
    If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
    -----
    Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:IN
    State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:X
    Locality Name (eg, city) []:Phillaur
    Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:      
    Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:server
    Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:rajanlagah
    Email Address []:rajanlagah@gmail.com
```

And

```
ls
cert.pem  key.pem
```

And

```
ubuntu@ip-172:/etc/letsencrypt/live/server.x.com$ openssl rsa -in cert.pem 
unable to load Private Key
140670293214872:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

Comment: Probably some issue with permissions on the key file. Just a hunch.

Comment: @Asdfg exactly but i have given permissions. How can i check if some are pending ?

Comment: Fyi, apache supports letsencrypt nativly via mod_md, it saves you a lot of hassle 
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_md.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if SSLCertificateKeyFile is pointing to a file containing a private key.i.e

```
# openssl rsa -in /opt/localhost.key -noout -check
RSA key ok
```

create a self sign certificate using `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365`.

Comment: Do i need to change the `opt/localhost.key` to something ?

Comment: This is an example to check whether the used ky file is in the proper format or not. You can replace your key path in the above example.

Comment: Hey i just updated my question with error i am facing after running this command

Comment: You can create a self sign certificate using `openssl req -new -x509 -key privkey.pem -out server-cert.pem -days 650`. Use generated key and certificate.
`

Comment: ok will do. And you are saying somehow previously generated certificate got corrupt right ?  And will accept your ans in few mins ( after trying ) :-)

Comment: Yup or maybe not generated properly.

Comment: Hey i created the certificate again. But when i run above command as sudo only then it sah SHA ok. Else it have same error

Comment: Please use below command to create certificate `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365` and test

Comment: When i run your command in ans it show `140060066858648:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
` After running openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365

Comment: When i `ls` then it show no prev key in that folder

Comment: Make sure that you have write permission for user. Please share whole  output with command.

Comment: It looks like a certificate and key generated. Could you please use a new generated key and certificate file. Also check `openssl rsa -in key.pem  -noout -check` command output.

Comment: this command is asking for Pass phrase and then output `RSA key ok`

Comment: It is showing proper output. You can use key and certificate.